# Pulling datagridview information from one form and using it in another

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

For example, say I have a main screen on a form that has a datagridview with a list of PC components, and buttons to add, remove, or modify components from this dgv. I want the user to be able to select a row from datagridview, and then click the modify button which will open a ModifyComponent form and the details of the selected component will populate in various textboxes. So I am looking to pull data from the selected row into the ModifyComponent form. This is how I have attempted it so far. I created this method in the MainScreen form (the row index is the same as a ComponentID property in a Components binding list) :

```
 public int getData()
    {
       int component = ComponentsGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index);
       return component;
    }
```

And then in the ModifyComponent form I use a lookupComponent method from the Inventory class that takes the component ID and pulls out the correct component from the Components list:

```
 Inventory.lookupComponent(MainScreen.getData());
```

I'll then write code to put each property in the correct textbox but I am getting an error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property MainScreen.getData". What would be a good direction to go to fix this or a different way to go about tackling this?

Comment: Sharing a single datasource between two form is easy.  You need to stop thinking of the data being "in" a control or rows - thats just how you display a VIEW of the DATA to the user in a GRID

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow I understand that the dgv is just displaying data from the list. I am essentially trying to transfer the info about which row is selected when the person clicks the modify button. I also get an error when trying to use the "ComponentsGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index" code in the Modify form

Comment: The index if the selected row(s) is a bad way to go about it.  If you have a `List<T>` extract the item and pass that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way to do it (C# translated).

Few things:

- you could share only a datarow between the forms, if you don't need access to whole datatable. However it's only a reference, it doesn't cost you much resources this way anyway.
- you should have DatagridView.Multiselect = False, if you're using SelectedIndex(0).
- this way you can also use functions in the parent form, i.e. call ParentF.ReloadData() after you modified the record, if you have such function for reloadin data set as *Public*.

C#

```
// Declare In Parent form (outside functions, in the head of class)
public DataTable dt = new DataTable();  // create *public* datatable

// Get data any way you like into datatable
string cmdTextTC = "SELECT TOP 1000 ID, Name, Componet FROM TestTable; ";   
DataSet ds;
ds = DataAccessLayer.GetQueryResultsTC(cmdText);
If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    dt = ds.Tables(0)
End If

// Use it for datagrid
this.DataGridViewComponents.datasource = dt;

// Declare In Child form (outside functions, in the head of class)
public MyParentForm ParentFrm;   // link to parent
public Int32 ComponentID;        // selected component

// When declaring child form in the parent, remember to set some relations
MyChildForm ChildForm; // child form
ChildForm.ParentFrm = this;     // create reference to parent
ChildForm.ComponentID = ComponentsGridView.SelectedRows(O).Index;  // Set Selected ID

// Use data in ChildForm
DataRow dr = ParentFrm.dt.rows(ComponentID);
this.NumericUpDownID.Value = System.Convert.ToInt32(dr("ID"));
this.TextBoxName.Text = System.Convert.ToString(dr("Name"));
```

VB Code

```
' Declare In Parent form (outside functions, in the head of class)
Public dt As New DataTable  ' create *public* datatable 

    ' Fill it any way you like (here I use a declared function)
    Dim cmdTextTC As String = "SELECT TOP 1000 ID, Name, Componet FROM TestTable; "
    Dim ds As DataSet
    ds = DataAccessLayer.GetQueryResultsTC(cmdText)
    If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        dt = ds.Tables(0)
    End If

    ' Use it for datagrid
    Me.DataGridViewComponents.datasource = dt

' Declare In Child form (outside functions, in the head of class)
Public ParentFrm As MyParentForm   ' link to parent
Public ComponentID As Int32        ' selected component

' When declaring child form in the parent, remember to set some relations
Dim ChildForm As MyChildForm ' child form
ChildForm.ParentFrm = Me     ' create reference to parent
ChildForm.ComponentID = ComponentsGridView.SelectedRows(O).Index  ' Set Selected ID

' Use data in ChildForm
Dim dr As DataRow = ParentFrm.dt.rows(ComponentID)
Me.NumericUpDownID.Value = CInt(dr("ID"))
Me.TextBoxName.Text = CStr(dr("Name"))
```